# monitoring region when app is shut down

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app I have called  `startMonitoringForRegion` for several regions. If I kill the app, the next time the app start. will it still be monitoring that region that I've set before until I actually call `stopMonitoringForRegion:` ? Or do I have to call startMonitoringForRegion all over again? If this is the case is there a way so that when the app starts it automatically monitors the region that I have monitored before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [CLLocationManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) docs (see the "Using Regions to Monitor Boundary Crossings" section) state:

> The regions you register with the
>   location manager persist between
>   launches of your application. If a
>   region crossing occurs while your
>   application is not running, the system
>   automatically wakes up your
>   application (or relaunches it) in the
>   background so that it can process the
>   event. When relaunched, all of the
>   regions you configured previously are
>   made available in the monitoredRegions
>   property of any location manager
>   objects you create.

Comment: oh I might have missed that =)

Comment: @EquinoX Let's face it, there's such a depth to Apple's excellent class docs, that's it's often a case of seeing the wood for the trees. Hope it goes well. :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you used region monitoring before?

Comment: @EquinoX Played around with it a while back, but nothing serious. i.e.: If you get *really* stuck, I wouldn't be the one answering the question here on SO. :-)

Comment: Did you test it on an actual device? Any comments with regards to it's accuracy? It heard it sucks balls

Comment: @EquinoX Didn't get that involved in it to be honest, but I was running it on an actual device. (It was an old iPod 2G, so the location info was based on an IP address based best guess, hence I couldn't really comment on the accuracy.)

Comment: @EquinoX I was talking about the CLLocationManager in general, which is supported by iOS 2.0 and up. (The boundary monitoring bits only appeared in iOS 4.0 if that's what you mean?)